# Qt3 to Qt4 class change

Tags: qt, user-interface, qt4, qt3

I am transferring some code form Qt3 to Qt4.

I can not find the `QDockWindow` class in Qt 4. What is corresponding class in Qt4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`QDockWidget` is the Qt4 equivalent.

If you are going through the pain of upgrading, would it make more sense to upgrade to Qt5 now?

Comment: Technically, the QtWidgets module in Qt4 is the same as in Qt5 so it doesn't make that much of a difference.

Comment: DO you konw what is the responding part of head file <qdict.h> in QT4? I have some code need using two Qt class named QDict and QDictIterator, but this is in QT3, I need transfer it to QT4, but in QT4 I can not find qdict.h.

Comment: `QMap<QString, T>` is probably the nearest equivalent.